# Prevent collider from moving parent Gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so at the moment my player is holding a gun which is parented to an empty gameObject which is a child of my player. In my game there are obstacles. When My gun collider with one of the obstacle colliders it will move my player as well which should not be the case as the player should say still. How do I make the collider of the player not be moved by a collision of the gun??

Comment: Why does the gun need a collider?

Comment: so it doesn't go through objects Abion47...

Comment: The gun is in your players hands, the player collider should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to achieve what you are looking for is to parent the gun to your player (as you did) but to set a collider only to your player. Sure the gun will go through walls or item (if you ever played FPS games, you must have noticed it's almost always the case), but you will be able to suppress this from the player point of view by using **Layers** and a second **Camera**.

- Parent your gun as child of your player (as you did)
- Create a new **Layer** named like "ArmsAndWeapons"
- Select your players arms and your weapon and set their layer to the newly created one
- Add a new **Camera** as child of your current main camera
- Change the new camera settings : set the *Clear Flags* to "Depth only", set the *Culling Mask* to your new layer only (you can also reduce the *Far Clipping Plane* value)
- Finally set the *Depth* of your new camera to something higher than the main camera you have

Hope this helps